# Total row count for pagination using JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin, pagination

I am implementing "Advanced Search" kind of functionality for an Entity in my system such that user can search that entity using multiple conditions(eq,ne,gt,lt,like etc) on attributes of this entity. I am using JPA's Criteria API to dynamically generate the Criteria query and then using `setFirstResult()` & `setMaxResults()` to support pagination. All was fine till this point but now I want to show total number of results on results grid but I did not see a straight forward way to get total count of Criteria query.
This is how my code looks like:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Brand> cQuery = builder.createQuery(Brand.class);
Root<Brand> from = cQuery.from(Brand.class);
CriteriaQuery<Brand> select = cQuery.select(from);
.
.
//Created many predicates and added to **Predicate[] pArray**
.
.
select.where(pArray);
// Added orderBy clause
TypedQuery typedQuery = em.createQuery(select);
typedQuery.setFirstResult(startIndex);
typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
List resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

My result set could be big so I don't want to load my entities for count query, so tell me efficient way to get total count like `rowCount()` method on Criteria (I think its there in Hibernate's Criteria).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks Vladimir!
I took your idea and used separate count query to use my existing array of predicates in it. Final implementation looks like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Brand> cQuery = builder.createQuery(Brand.class);
Root<Brand> from = cQuery.from(Brand.class);
CriteriaQuery<Brand> select = cQuery.select(from);
.
.
//Created many predicates and added to **Predicate[] pArray**
.
.
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
cq.select(builder.count(cq.from(Brand.class)));
// Following line if commented causes [org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.enabled' [select count(generatedAlias0) from xxx.yyy.zzz.Brand as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias1.enabled=:param0 ) and ( lower(generatedAlias1.description) like :param1 )]]
em.createQuery(cq);
cq.where(pArray);
Long count = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
.
.
select.where(pArray);
.
.
// Added orderBy clause
TypedQuery typedQuery = em.createQuery(select);
typedQuery.setFirstResult(startIndex);
typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
List resultList = typedQuery.getResultList()
```

Though this is working fine but still I am not sure why I have to write

```
em.createQuery(cq);
```

to get it working. Any Idea?

Comment: Were you able to find out why exactly you need to add the `em.createQuery(cq);`? Thanks

Comment: Hey, this is just what I needed... bu I would also like to know why this line is neccessary !?

Comment: I suspect it is to do with the fact that the `Predicate`s are being built using the `Root<>` from this part `Root<Brand> from = cQuery.from(Brand.class);` and are then used for both the count query and the paged query. AFAIK you need to build the predicates twice using both `Root<>` objects. The second one is hidden in this line `cq.select(builder.count(cq.from(Brand.class)));`. Why exactly `em.createQuery(cq);` works I don't know, IMO it should throw an exception.

Comment: Why don't we just get it from resultList.size() ?

Comment: For anyone wondering if this issue still exists, yes it does (as of v2.7.13). You still need to add the extra `em.createQuery(cq);` to get this to work. I tried the suggestion from @Neilos by creating two different roots (one for the count, one for the data) and building the predicates twice using each root. Still results in the same exception. Perhaps you need to create a separate `CriteriaQuery` for the separate count root too. Regardless, this is too many extra steps IMO for a simple count query. Easier just to add the extra `em.createQuery(cq);` and stay in wonder of why it works :)

Comment: Adding to my previous comment after some more debugging, this solution does not work if you intend on performing and querying on joins. In this case, you do need to set up the queries properly. Create a `CriteriaQuery<Brand>` for your data query, and a `CriteriaQuery<Long>` for your count query. Create roots for each `CriteriaQuery` and add the predicates to both roots. Redundant, I know. But this seems to be the most effective way of achieving this.

Answer (score 16):

Why don't you just use count?

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Brand> from = cQuery.from(Brand.class);
CriteriaQuery<Long> select = cQuery.select(builder.count(from));
.
.
//Created many predicates and added to **Predicate[] pArray**
.
.
select.where(pArray);
// Added orderBy clause
TypedQuery<Long> typedQuery = em.createQuery(select);
typedQuery.setFirstResult(startIndex);
//typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
// here is the size of your query 
Long result = typedQuery.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Hibernate as your JPA-Provider have a look at [projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection), especially `Projections.rowCount()`.

You might have to execute the query twice though, first get the count then get the results.

Note that for plain JPA you might need some other approach.

Comment: -1. The OP quite clearly stated he's looking for ansers with respect to "JPA Criteria API", don't you think your answer is somewhat misleading? (Implying the hibernate projections is the way to do this). I'm saying this because when I stumbled on to the question I saw your answer first and it confused me into thinking that's the way (especially since there was an add between you and the next answer which made you the only visible answer).

Comment: I think that when you read the question you see that it's not about hibernate, It's just that a lot of times in SO you see that people answer what they think the OP needs and not what the OP requests. Since it seems like an honest mistake if you'll edit your question I'll change my vote.

Answer (score 0):

I guess both of the answers work. But none of them is optimal. The problem with ThinkFloyd's answer is that `createQuery` is used two times. And `Vladimir Ivanov` has created two instances of `CriteriaQuery` which I think is unnecessary.

```
val cb = entityManager.criteriaBuilder
val cq = cb.createQuery(ManualQuery::class.java)
val manualQuery = cq.from(ManualQuery::class.java)

val predicates = ArrayList<Predicate>()

/*
predications..... 
*/ 

cq.select(manualQuery)
        .where(*predicates.toTypedArray())
        .orderBy(cb.desc(manualQuery.get<ZonedDateTime>("createdDate")))

val query = entityManager.createQuery(cq)

// total rows count
val count = query.resultList.size

val indexedQuery = query
        .setFirstResult((currentPage - 1) * pageSize)
        .setMaxResults(itemsPerPage)
```

Doing go it works. And it is done in **Kotlin**. You do it the same way in **Java**.

Comment: The downside to this is that you get the full result set just to count the rows, then you get the paged results afterwards. If you have to do two separate queries, it's better to just select the count then get the paginated results.

Comment: @jason could you add your solution?