# Getting records by groups in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0, batch-processing

I am writing a batch and using JPA for persistence. I have a table with a lot of records and I need to read all the records by groups of 100 or 500. I don't want to load all the records into memory at once, because there won't be enough memory.

For example:

- First group: records 1 to 500
- Second group: records 501 to 1000
- etc

Is there a better way to do it?

---

Related questions

[JPA: what is the proper pattern for iterating over large result sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067619/jpa-what-is-the-proper-pattern-for-iterating-over-large-result-sets)

[Total row count for pagination using JPA Criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349264/total-row-count-for-pagination-using-jpa-criteria-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the first result and the number of results in your javax.persistence.Query with methods setFirstResult() and setMaxResults().

Comment: Thank you! I used a variable to use the first result number, initialised to 0. Then I setted the number of max results, and then I made the interrogation to the DB using the query() method. Last thing to do was incrementing the first result by the number of max results of the previous query.