# Get rowCount before execute query JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to build a Pagination inside my system. In DAO i'm using "setFirstResult()" and "setMaxResults()" to limit the amount of rows returned.

Look:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);

        if (firstResult != null) {
        query.setFirstResult(firstResult);
        }

        if (maxResult != null) {
        query.setMaxResults(maxResult);
        }

        List returnList = query.getResultList();
```

But for pagination works i need to know the amount of rows without limitation (firstResult() and maxResults()).

If i have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.car = :carParam OFFSET 10 LIMIT 20
```

i would like to count like this

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.car = :carParam
```

But I want to avoid create another query manually for each Entity, how can i do a count() without force creating a new count() query ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Total row count for pagination using JPA Criteria API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349264/total-row-count-for-pagination-using-jpa-criteria-api)

Comment: I'm not using Criteria

Comment: You can't. You must issue a separate `count(*)` since SQL queries don't intrinsically return the total number of matching records.

Comment: that's what I feared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to calculate the total count of results without using Criteria API or (as you said) creating another query manually. Both of them will cause to a separate query against database to calculate the total counts. I had some experiences in this context. It may doubles your response time if your query is going to be run on a huge data set or if you have a large number of concurrent users.

I think the best way to prevent such an overhead on your DBMS is to display a "load more" link at the end of the search results. I highly recommend such approach if displaying total count is not part of your main business or is not forced by the client.

Take a look at [this](http://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination) link (if you've not checked it before)

Comment: The "load more" really is the best solution, i didn't think about it. I will use this solution, thanks.